# Spring AMQP RabbitMQ RPC - Handle response exceptions

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying to use a RPC AMQP RabbitMQ queue to send and receive messages.  The problem is that I have set a setReplyTimeout value.  When that happens I get a "org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Reply received after timeout".  I have a DLQ set up on the incoming queue, but it appears that the exception is received when spring tries to return the message on its queue that is automatically created.  Thus how can I handle exceptions when sending messages back to a producer?  Ideally I would want any message that gets an exception while being sent to a producer sent to a DLQ.

I am using

```
@RabbitListener(queues = QueueConfig.QUEUE_ALL, containerFactory = "containerFactoryQueueAll")
```

It requires a SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory which does not have setQueues. Also rabbitTemplate does not have a rabbitTemplate.setReplyQueue

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the default built-in reply listener container with the direct reply-to pseudo queue, use a [Reply Listener Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#reply-listener) with a named queue that is configured to route undeliverable messages to a DLQ.

The `RabbitTemplate` is configured as the container's listener:

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate amqpTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(msgConv());
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyQueue(replyQueue());
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(60000);
    rabbitTemplate.setUseDirectReplyToContainer(false);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyListenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    container.setQueues(replyQueue());
    container.setMessageListener(amqpTemplate());
    return container;
}

@Bean
public Queue replyQueue() {
    return new Queue("my.reply.queue");
}
```

Note that the documentation needs to be updated, but you also need

```
rabbitTemplate.setUseDirectReplyToContainer(false);
```

**IMPORTANT**

If you have multiple instances of the client, each needs its own reply queue.

Comment: I am using @RabbitListener(queues = QueueConfig.QUEUE_ALL, containerFactory = "containerFactoryQueueAll")  It requires a SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory which does not have setQueues.  Also rabbitTemplate does not have a rabbitTemplate.setReplyQueue

Comment: Don't put code in comments; edit the question instead. The reply container can't be a `@RabbitListener`, it must be a discrete `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` with the container as the listener. Sorry - `setReplyQueue()` was deprecated in 1.7.x; it's now `setReplyAddress` which can be a simple queue name, or `exchange/routingKey`.

Comment: Sorry havent ever been asked to not put code in comments, so wasnt aware.  I will edit the question and put my last comment there.

Comment: Well shoot, I was really hoping to use a RabbitListener.

Comment: ?? How would you expect to use a `@RabbitListener` to handle the reply on the client side when the reply has to go to the template? Of course, you can use one on the server side.

Comment: I guess my question then is, How do I specify which @RabbitListener on the server side that a SimpleMessageListernContainer correlates to.  I need different concurrency and prefetch for different listeners.  My solution before was by using a SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory

Comment: That is unrelated; your question was about sending a late reply (client side) to a DLQ; you can only do that with a named reply queue. The SMLC is for handling replies on the client side, it is unrelated to the listener container on the server side. BTW, on the server side, you can now (since 2.0) override the container factory concurrency (but not prefetch) setting directly on the `@RabbitListener` annotation.