# Spring AMQP RabbitMQ - Error Handling for Direct reply-to

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying to handle exceptions that are resulting from a amq.rabbitmq.reply-to queue specificially things like: "org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Reply received after timeout".  How can I configure something so I can handle these exceptions?  I have tried setting the setErrorHandler properity, but it appears to do nothing.  If I get an error on my input queue the handler works, but not with the RPC response queue.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [Spring AMQP RabbitMQ RPC - Handle response exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748079/spring-amqp-rabbitmq-rpc-handle-response-exceptions) you need an explicit reply container to handle replies with more sophistication; you can wire an error handler into that container.

There is currently no support for adding an error handler to the built-in direct reply-to container.

Consider opening a [new feature issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).

This would be a rather trivial enhancement.

Comment: The issue, If I understand it correctly, with making a container/reply queue of my own for RPC is that it has to be exclusive.  Is that accurate?

Comment: That is correct; if you have multiple client instances they each need a unique reply queue - but it can be an `AnonymousQueue` (random name, auto-delete). But to ensure absolutely zero message (reply) loss, it would need to be a durable queue with a unique name for each client instance.

Comment: That was my issue I have multiple clients.  I did not think about making the response queue an AnonymousQueue though.  I will see if I can get my scenario to work that way.  Thanks for the Idea!

Comment: Thank you very much!  I will follow that feature request.